# Post a huge html form by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to send a html form consisting of more than 100 sub fieldsets of 10 elements which it totally a huge form of more than 1000 elements.

I use jQuery to send this form. The problem is that it doesn't send all of the elements (it sends 84 sub fields out of 100).

I've been searching a lot but I have not found a reason or solution. Is it a limitation of jQuery or HTML or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#video_table", function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    var image_load = "<img src='/img/loading.gif' />";
    $("#videoupdate-div").html(image_load);

    // $.post(action, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        // $("#videoupdate-div").html(data);
    // });

    $.ajax({
        //dataType: "json",
        url : action,
        type : "POST",
        data :  $(this).serialize() ,
        success : function(result) {
            $("#videoupdate-div").html(result);
        },
        error : function(result) {
            $("#videoupdate-div").html("Error! Something must be wrong.");
        }
    });


    return false;
});
```

Comment: I would like to meet the person that has the patience of filling in 1000 entries. He is a saint/idiot.

Comment: @EdHeal I believe almost all these fields are hidden

Comment: Does the same problem happen if you remove jQuery from the equation and just submit the form?

Comment: check all fields are contained within the form element.

Comment: Your server will most likely deny the request long before the client would choke. (if it was a numbers issue.) (Nuke attack). I would make sure that everything you expect to be part of your form, is actually part of your form.

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk - Your faith is stronger than mine.

Comment: @EdHeal govt. and other public service organisations like a lot of fields in their forms. they're usually not too concerned about the effort required by an individual in filling them in.

Comment: @dewd - they usually split them up into pages. And yes they are concerned in them being filled in correctly.

Comment: @EdHeal if wordpress gravityforms is used by govt. institutions (as it is by some),  they can use paging for larger forms. However, all a page is (with gravityforms), is an interim submission. With each page change, the full form is submitted with fields not on the given page hidden in some way.

Comment: @dewd - Do they (on your neck of the woods) have the concept of being able to come back to the form. I.e. not the whole thing on one page where bits are not necessary

Comment: @EdHeal funny you should say that. i'm working on a project within which we're introducing the concept of a user object. this gets updated and validated between the server and client asyncronously with every field change - client side validation first > server side verification/ reconciliation. the user object is saved, so the user can/ will continue from where they've left off. the user object gets finalised at final submission. it's a single page app with full history navigation. hopefully it's going to improve the visitor experience no end.

Answer (score 2):

The form's own submission likely interferes with the submit event

Change

```
$(document).on("submit", "#video_table", function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on("submit", "#video_table", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the form's own submit
```

PS If the form is not dynamically inserted into the DOM, then this is enough

```
$("#video_table").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of these worked, I don't know whether it helps or not to mention that my form is being built dynamically based on some records coming from my database.

Comment: Any messages in the console? Any errors on the server?

Comment: Firebug console (on firefox) doesn't record any errors on executing j-query lines and I can print the posted data in my php page . In fact it sounds like it works correctly(sending information to the php page) except the fact that it doesn't send all of the information . bizarre! By the way I have to thank you for your time and attention .